# ASP.NET Get all TreeView nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, treenode

Is there a way to get all the `TreeNode` objects inside a `TreeView` control without iterating through the `TreeView.Nodes` and `TreeNode.ChildNodes` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not get all TreeView nodes without iterating Nodes and ChildNodes.